# POST XML file using cURL command line

Tags: xml, command-line, curl

How can I POST an XML file to a local server `http://localhost:8080` using cURL from the command line?

What command should I use?

Answer (score 534, accepted):

If that question is connected to your other Hudson questions use the command they provide.  This way with XML from the command line:

```
$ curl -X POST -d '<run>...</run>' \
http://user:pass@myhost:myport/path/of/url
```

You need to change it a little bit to read from a file:

```
 $ curl -X POST -d @myfilename http://user:pass@myhost:myport/path/of/url
```

Read the [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). following an abstract for -d Parameter.

> -d/--data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a
>   POST request to the HTTP server, in
>   the same way that a browser does when
>   a user has filled in an HTML form and
>   presses the submit button. This will
>   cause curl to pass the data to the
>   server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>   Compare to -F/--form.
>
> -d/--data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should
>   instead use the --data-binary option.
>   To URL-encode the value of a form
>   field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more
>   than once on the same command line,
>   the data pieces specified will be
>   merged together with a separating
>   &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel
>   -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like
>   'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter
>   @, the rest should be a file name to
>   read the data from, or - if you want
>   curl to read the data from stdin. The
>   contents of the file must already be
>   URL-encoded. Multiple files can also
>   be specified. Posting data from a file
>   named 'foobar' would thus be done with
>   --data @foobar.

Comment: thanks Peter a lot!! you were bang on. it's related to that only and u  are absolutely correct..thanks once again. :-)

Comment: Read the manpage. `The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded.` OP's XML files surely aren't.

Comment: So long as you specify the content-type `--header "Content-Type:application/xml"` you aren't expected to [URL-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: I'll just add that if you use "-d" it defaults to POST, so there is no need to use "-X" as well.

Comment: if you are using curl's follow redirects option `-L`, do *not* use `-X POST` as it will make redirected request use POST too.  If you just use -d as @Tai suggests, this won't happen

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty curl command to run from a windows command line. I had trouble with the single quotes; seems to be a linux-windows disparity. Anyway, here you go: curl -X POST -d "<run><log>4142430A</log><result>0</result><duration>2000</duration></run>" http://localhost:8080/ControllerName/ActionName

Comment: As of curl 7.18.0 there is also a `--data-urlencode <data>` option which will do the URL-encoding for you

Comment: The command in this answer didn't work for me. `curl -F filedata=@myfile.foo http://127.0.0.1:8080` worked instead.

Comment: Be warned that `-d` strips line breaks from files. To avoid this, use `--data-binary` instead.

Comment: @RandallCook Apparently because your server expected to see multipart/form-data, not a binary blob. Both cases have their [uses](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/246#issuecomment-669265388).

Answer (score 197):

From the [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), I believe these are the droids you are looking for:

> `-F/--form <name=content>`
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign.
>
> Example, to send your password file to the server, where 'password' is the name of the form-field to which /etc/passwd will be the input:
>
> `curl -F password=@/etc/passwd www.mypasswords.com`

So in your case, this would be something like
`curl -F file=@/some/file/on/your/local/disk http://localhost:8080`

Comment: This solution has the added benefit of being able to name the file being sent (unlike the chosen solution above), and you can therefore e.g. send multiple files.

Comment: The format `file=@-` is helpful if you want to pipe your file in.

Comment: In case anyone is looking to send a file and other information: use -F key=val -F key=val as many times as you need. Enclosing all post parameters in one large string separated by & does not work.

Comment: Can you mention how to prepare the receiving web page to be able to receive the files uploaded via curl from desktop?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Like any other file upload field; there is no special handling specifically for curl.

Comment: Oh okay, so just like a normal backend web page handles a file upload say through a form, same here as well?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yes. Essentially, cURL simulates a browser's behavior here.

Answer (score 53):

You can using option --data with file.

Write xml content to a file named is soap_get.xml and using curl command to send request:

> curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @soap_get.xml your_url

Comment: This should be the answer since the OP is asking about posting a file not inline text.

Comment: This was necessary for it to show up "non escaped" for me using spring web server, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

With Jenkins 1.494, I was able to send a file to a job parameter on Ubuntu Linux 12.10 using `curl` with `--form` parameters:

```sh
curl --form name=myfileparam --form file=@/local/path/to/your/file.xml \
  -Fjson='{"parameter": {"name": "myfileparam", "file": "file"}}' \
  -Fsubmit=Build \
  http://user:password@jenkinsserver/job/jobname/build
```

On the Jenkins server, I configured a job that accepts a single parameter: a file upload parameter named `myfileparam`.

The first line of that curl call constructs a web form with a parameter named `myfileparam` (same as in the job); its value will be the contents of a file on the local file system named `/local/path/to/your/file.txt`. The `@` symbol prefix tells curl to send a local file instead of the given filename.

The second line defines a JSON request that matches the form parameters on line one: a file parameter named `myfileparam`.

The third line activates the form's Build button. The forth line is the job URL with the "/build" suffix.

If this call is successful, curl returns `0`. If it is unsuccessful, the error or exception from the service is printed to the console. This answer takes a lot from [an old blog post relating to Hudson](http://illegalstateexception.blogspot.ca/2010/11/triggering-hudson-parameterized-builds.html), which I deconstructed and re-worked for my own needs.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you can POST XML on Windows using curl command line on Windows. Better use batch/.cmd file for that:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d             ^
"^<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?^>                ^
    ^<Transaction^>                                           ^
        ^<SomeParam1^>Some-Param-01^</SomeParam1^>            ^
        ^<Password^>SomePassW0rd^</Password^>                 ^
        ^<Transaction_Type^>00^</Transaction_Type^>           ^
        ^<CardHoldersName^>John Smith^</CardHoldersName^>     ^
        ^<DollarAmount^>9.97^</DollarAmount^>                 ^
        ^<Card_Number^>4111111111111111^</Card_Number^>       ^
        ^<Expiry_Date^>1118^</Expiry_Date^>                   ^
        ^<VerificationStr2^>123^</VerificationStr2^>          ^
        ^<CVD_Presence_Ind^>1^</CVD_Presence_Ind^>            ^
        ^<Reference_No^>Some Reference Text^</Reference_No^>  ^
        ^<Client_Email^>john@smith.com^</Client_Email^>       ^
        ^<Client_IP^>123.4.56.7^</Client_IP^>                 ^
        ^<Tax1Amount^>^</Tax1Amount^>                         ^
        ^<Tax2Amount^>^</Tax2Amount^>                         ^
    ^</Transaction^>                                          ^
" "http://localhost:8080"
```

Comment: How do u format the xml string before using with curl command

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: <<Removed>>' -F file=@"/home/xxx/Desktop/customers.json"  'API_SERVER_URL' -k
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **curl** on Windows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<?xml version="""1.0""" encoding="""UTF-8""" standalone="""yes"""?><message><sender>Me</sender><content>Hello!</content></message>" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/hello
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple headers then you might want to use the following:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "X-Auth:AuthKey" --data @hello.json Your_url
```

Answer (score -1):

Powershell + Curl + Zimbra SOAP API

```
${my_xml} = @"
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
  <soapenv:Body>
   <GetFolderRequest xmlns=\"urn:zimbraMail\">
    <folder>
       <path>Folder Name</path>
    </folder>
   </GetFolderRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@

${my_curl} = "c:\curl.exe"
${cookie} = "c:\cookie.txt"

${zimbra_soap_url} = "https://zimbra:7071/service/admin/soap"
${curl_getfolder_args} = "-b", "${cookie}",
            "--header", "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            "--silent",
            "--data-raw", "${my_xml}",
            "--url", "${zimbra_soap_url}"

[xml]${my_response} = & ${my_curl} ${curl_getfolder_args}
${my_response}.Envelope.Body.GetFolderResponse.folder.id
```

Comment: The question is not asking to use powershell + curl + zimbra SOAP API