# Send request to cURL with post data sourced from a file

Tags: http, curl, http-post, command-line-interface

I need to make a POST request via cURL from the command line. Data for this request is located in a file. I know that via PUT this could be done with the `--upload-file` option.

```bash
curl host:port/post-file -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data "contents_of_file"
```

Comment: Check my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php/6213693#6213693

Comment: Sorry maybe i mistakenly described my problem i need to send request not via php-curl but just via curl command from command line from linux os.

Comment: See also [send/post xml file using curl command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line).

Answer (score 560, accepted):

You're looking for the `--data-binary` argument:

```bash
curl -i -X POST host:port/post-file \
  -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \
  --data-binary "@path/to/file"
```

In the example above, `-i` prints out all the headers so that you can see what's going on, and `-X POST` makes it explicit that this is a post.  Both of these can be safely omitted without changing the behaviour on the wire.  The path to the file needs to be preceded by an `@` symbol, so `curl` knows to read from a file.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ in this case it would be `.xml`

Comment: the `@` part is extremely important!

Comment: So we use --data-binary parameter, but the actual file content can be text? Since XML isn't typically binary.

Comment: yeah, the file content can be anything.  If you want to make sure that the server knows that you're giving it xml, then the -H "Content-Type: text/xml" will do that for you.

Comment: actually you can use just -d flag

Comment: @Tol182 `-d` will cause `curl` to strip newlines, but `--data-binary` won't.

Comment: For those that can't get it to work, make sure that you are specifying the content type in your headers!

Comment: If you're executing the curl command from the same path as your data file, its just  `--data-binary "@file"`.

Comment: does curl allow an ip address in the hostname parameter?

Answer (score 121):

> I need to make a POST request via Curl from the command line. Data for this request is located in a file...

All you need to do is have the `--data` argument start with a `@`:

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data "@path_of_file" host:port/post-file-path
```

For example, if you have the data in a file called `stuff.xml` then you would do something like:

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data "@stuff.xml" host:port/post-file-path
```

The `stuff.xml` filename can be replaced with a relative or full path to the file:  `@../xml/stuff.xml`, `@/var/tmp/stuff.xml`, ...

Comment: In case you need to send a named field, you can also use `--data "name@stuff"`.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using  form data to upload file,in which a parameter name must be specified , you can use:

`curl  -X POST  -i  -F "parametername=@filename" -F "additional_parm=param2" host:port/xxx`

Answer (score 8):

Most of answers are perfect here, but when I landed here for my particular problem, I have to upload binary file (XLSX spread sheet) using POST method, I see one thing **missing**, i.e. usually its not just file you load, you may have more **form data elements**, *like comment to file or tags to file* etc as was my case. Hence, I would like to add it here as it was my use case, so that it could help others.

```
curl -POST -F comment=mycomment -F file_type=XLSX -F file_data=@/your/path/to/file.XLSX http://yourhost.example.com/api/example_url
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue in passing the file as a param. Using -F allowed the file to be passed as form data, but the content type of the file was application/octet-stream. My endpoint was expecting text/csv.

You are able to set the MIME type of the file with the following syntax:

```bash
-F 'file=@path/to/file;type=<MIME_TYPE>'
```

So the full cURL command would look like this for a CSV file:

```bash
curl -X POST -F 'file=@path/to/file.csv;type=text/csv' https://test.com
```

There is good documentation on this and other options here: https://catonmat.net/cookbooks/curl/make-post-request#post-form-data

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a HTTP connection, because on HTTPS there is default file size limit.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Solution-for-Request-Entity-Too-Large-error/ba-p/501134

```bash
curl -i -X 'POST' -F 'file=@/home/testeincremental.xlsx' 'http://example.com/upload.aspx?user=example&password=example123&type=XLSX'
```

Comment: This only applies to windows servers running IIS with the default limit in place. Outside of that, most websites these days will force HTTPs. If the server is one you control, you can just increase the file size limit if that is a viable use case for your service.