# Send POST Request wget

Tags: php, linux, post, csv, wget

I am trying to save a CSV file that has a do post back link. I currently have the headers and cookies but am not getting the csv file with wget.

Here is the headers:

```
POST /sportsbook_spy/default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: pregame.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://pregame.com/sportsbook_spy/default.aspx
Cookie: Ccd=035ad31fe6ae4ecfa471cb7cb6f3a487b42fd4986df80e1a; Scd=0ad1b088c2c4b0097b3a7d3b32c34ec9d1585fde04336f0b; ASP.NET_SessionId=hzk5pwlo3y3kdwuuybcxoliq; AuthorizationCookie=6688A75D-8B99-4CD2-80C5-595236C99E47;
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 1092
```

For the command I am using

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --post-file post-file http://pregame.com/sportsbook_spy/default.aspx
```

How do I get this CSV file with a POST request?

Answer (score -5):

Try with cUrl command

```
curl -i -X POST http://pregame.com/sportsbook_spy/default.aspx -H "Content-Type: text/csv" --data-binary "@file.csv"
```

[Send POST Request with Data Specified in File via Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/how-to-send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl)

Comment: I still am just getting the html of the page when I used curl -i -X POST http://pregame.com/sportsbook_spy/default.aspx -H "Content-Type: text/csv" --data-binary "@postfile"

  --data-binary <data>
              (HTTP)  This  posts  data  exactly  as  specified  with no extra processing whatsoever.

Comment: The question asks how to send a `POST` request using `wget`, not `curl`.