# How can I upload zip file on HTML link , By shell script or terminal

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

My zip file is on my desktop. location (/home/User/Desktop/example.zip) I want to upload that file on this by terminal or shell script. Is there is any solution?

Here is my destination
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfiBC.jpg

Comment: Create Script To Upload Your Zip File

Comment: Please share example about my question

Comment: Take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773724/curl-http-post-file-upload-using-curl-data-in-linux-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to upload a file with a script. You can do that simply by recording a macro in Firefox.

[Refer Tutorial:](http://www.howtogeek.com/113789/how-to-automate-repetitive-web-browser-tasks-with-imacros/)

Comment: Short similar. I want my zip file upload on specific link.
My source is:  (Example/Desktop/example.zip)
Destination is: (script or terminal open Firefox and open specific weblink which i give in script.)
processs of script: pick zip file from my ubuntu desktop and drop it on specific weblink ..

Comment: curl -T <filename> -u <username>:<password> <url> i used this command
(WebDAV) is an extension of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is Weblink extension ...