# CURL doesn't encode UTF-8

Tags: jquery, curl, encoding, utf-8, cmd

I'm using *Windows 10* and *curl 7.52.1*.
When I try to `POST` data to a WEBSERVICE, *curl* isn't encoding the characters to `UTF-8` (I need to display **pt-BR** characters, like **àáçÇãõ** etc)

Yes, I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how), no success.

If I set the encoding page to `chcp 65001`, the error persists.
Changing to `chcp 1252` solved the problem partially.

Look, if I prompt `echo Administração >> test.txt` without any `chcp` change, I get an **Administra‡Æo**.

After change to `chcp 65001` I get **AdministraÃ§Ã£o**.

After change to `chcp 1252` I finally get **Administração**.

But using `curl,` nothing change.

I've tried setting a header *content-type*, no lucky:

```
curl -X POST -h "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" --data-ascii "name=Administração" http//:localhost:8084/ws/departments
```

I get the following output:

**`{"holder":{"entities":[{"name":"Administraï¿½ï¿½o","dateReg":"Dec 29, 2016 2:05:33 PM"}],"sm":{}},"message":{"text":""},"status":-1}`**

I have also checked the **WS** it's accepting the characters encoding, when I run (in `JQuery`):

```
$.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost:8084/ws/departments",
     type:"POST",
     data: {name: "Administração"},
     success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
       console.log(data);
     }
});
```

I get the output expected:

**`{"holder":{"entities":[{"name":"Administração","dateReg":"Dec 29, 2016 2:03:17 PM"}],"sm":{}},"message":{"text":""},"status":-1}`**

I don't know what else can I try to solve this.
Please, could you guys help me?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @Dekel, I tried also using an external file as data-bynary (the content inside `test.txt` is **name=Administração**):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" --data-binary "@test.txt" http://localhost:8084/ws/departments
```

I still get this unusual output:

```
**{"holder":{"entities":[{"name":"Administraï¿½ï¿½o","dateReg":"Dec 29, 2016 2:41:27 PM"}],"sm":{}},"message":{"text":""},"status":-1}**
```

**UPDATE 2**

@Phylogenesis suggested to use `charset=ISO-8859-1`. I noticed that even returning **AdministraÃ**§Ã£o as result, checking narrowly in the server-side, the WS is receiving the exact letter, in this case `ç`.

Comment: Use binary data (and make sure the file's encoding is correct) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl

Comment: What happens if you use `charset=ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: @Dekel, echoing to a file is just an example, in fact I would like to POST data as a html form (x-www-form-urlencoded).

Comment: I didn't mean to echo to a file. Use the file as the input (not as output). This way you have full control on the encoding (and you are not tied to the encoding of your console).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, running `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1" --data-ascii "name=Administração" http://localhost:8084/ws/departments` I get: `{"holder":{"entities":[{"name":"AdministraÃ§Ã£o","dateReg":"Dec 29, 2016 2:34:19 PM"}],"sm":{}},"message":{"text":""},"status":-1}`. The character changed but still not showing the exact word, in this case `ç`.

Comment: @Dekel, I will try it and give a feedback.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro how did you save the test.txt file? what is the encoding of it's content?

Comment: @Dekel, just create using standard windows file creation: mouse right click > new text file > type name=Administração > save file > close.

Comment: And how do you know that the content of the file is encoded in UTF8? :) Open the file in a *real* text editor (you can use notepad++ for example), just don't use windows' notepad, and check the file's encoding.

Comment: btw, you can use https://httpbin.org/ for your tests. POST anything you want to `https://httpbin.org/post` and you will receive the exact data you just posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131826/discussion-between-andrew-ribeiro-and-dekel).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a discussion with @Dekel and a suggestion coming from @Phylogenesis I could resolve the problem partially, but effectively. There are 2 ways:

- `charset=ISO-8859-1`
- encoding a file and sending as binary-data

The server could receive the correct letter using `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Even the response data from server showing incorrectly.

I use: `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1" --data-ascii "name=Administração" http://localhost:8084/ws/departments`

The second way is encoding a file containing all the content you want to POST. I used *Notepad++ > Format > Convert to UTF-8 (Without BOM)*.

Then, prompt: `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" --data-binary "@test.txt" http://localhost:8084/ws/departments`.

Comment: Got my vote for taking the time and write the solution you found :)