# What is the reason for curl --data-urlencode error on running curl from within a Windows batch script?

Tags: azure, curl, cmd

I am using the *Text Analytics* service (find the language) of the *Azure* portal and a Windows batch script with *Curl* which is sending JSON data:

The following Windows batch script using `curl` and the `--data` option works:

```
set data="{'documents':[{'id':1,'text':'your are my guest'}]}"

curl -X POST %endpoint% ^
-H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--data %data%
```

However, it does not work when I want to use the `--data-urlencode` option with the same code.

The output error is:

```
Request body must be present
```

I have tried many things (double quote, escape, and so on), but nothing works.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383336/curl-doesnt-encode-utf-8)

The trick is to use a ('Notepad++' UTF-8 without BOM) file, say data.txt, with the --data-binary option :

```
curl -X POST %endpoint% ^
-H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--data-binary @data.txt
```

Inside the file data.txt :

```
{'documents':[{'id':1,'text':'your are my guest'}]}
```

But it works with any language (chinese, hindi, etc...), so you don't have to encode anything. For instance, you could have use, in the data.txt file

```
{'documents':[{'id':2,'text':'大都会区有它自己的当地路边快餐口味'}]}
```