# Flask+cURL concatenates multi-line CSV input into a single string

Tags: curl, flask

I have a route in my `flask` app that starts off like this:

```
@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    """
    Do an inference on a single batch of data.
    """
    if flask.request.content_type == 'text/csv':
        X_train = flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')
        X_train = pd.read_csv(StringIO(X_train), header=None).values
```

To test this path I am sending a `POST` request to the server from a `csv` formatted file with multiple lines in it: `curl -X "POST" -H "Content-Type: text/csv" -d @health-check-data.csv http://localhost:5000/invocations`.

However, to my surprise, when I execute `X_train = flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')`, I get the contents of the `csv` concatenated into a single string with newlines removed.

Why is `flask` (or `curl`?) doing this, and how do I get around this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

That's just the expected behavior for `flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')` -- it returns a string.

You can convert that string to a buffer that `read_csv` can read:

```
upload = flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')
buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write(upload)
buffer.seek(0)
X_train = pd.read_csv(buffer), header=None).values
```

However, you can bypass that process by reading the csv file via Flask's `request.files.get` which returns a buffer:

```
X_train = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('name'),  header=None).values
```

Comment: As I understand this answer is actually incorrect. For the second part: I am running `POST` from the command line with the `-d` argument, and that data is not being passed through a form, so `request.files` is empty. For the first part: `cURL` will strip newlines when passed data with the `-d` flag ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl#comment70445817_6409028)). You can avoid this behavior by using the `--data-binary` flag, which is what I did, and that worked. So the data is already mangled by the time it hits `flask`.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the [`man` entry](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) for the `curl -d` doesn't specify _how_ the encoding is handled. I wonder how else the `-d` flag mutates input...

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur Ahh, I see that you edited your question after I posted my answer to now say `string with newlines removed` instead of the original `string with no newlines removed` -- that is a very different meaning for this question :)

Comment: Yes, that was a terrible, no good, very bad typo, my apologies!