# How to trigger TeamCity build from Command Line using REST API?

Tags: command-line, teamcity

I am trying to trigger TeamCity build from command line.
Firstly, I tried:

```
curl http://<user name>:<user password>@<server address>/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=<build configuration Id>
```

But in latest versions of TeamCity this approach is removed and response is following:

405 Only POST method is allowed for this request.

So, based on information from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest-api.html#RESTAPI-BuildRequests it should work via REST API in this way:

```
url -v -u user:password http://teamcity.server.url:8111/app/rest/buildQueue --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @build.xml
```

build.xml example:

```
build.xml
<build>
    <buildType id="buildConfID"/>
</build>
```

For me is not clear where should I place my configured build.xml?

Comment: the curl `--data-binary` flag takes a filename as relative or absolute path (see [here](https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html) ), therefore as it stands it will be looking for your build.xml file in the root directory. You can also specify an absolute path by doing `--data-binary @path/to/file` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409028/3110529)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -u user:password  -X POST \
  https://teamcity.host.io/app/rest/buildQueue \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -H 'Host: teamcity.host.io' \
  -d '<build branchName="refs/heads/master">
  <triggeringOptions cleanSources="true" rebuildAllDependencies="false" queueAtTop="false"/>
  <buildType id="Test_Configuration_ID_for_trigger"/>
   <lastChanges>
    <change locator="version:e2418b4d7ae55ac4610dbff51bffe60d1f32e019"/>
  </lastChanges>
   <properties>
        <property name="env.startedBy" value="build was triggering from %teamcity.serverUrl%/viewLog.html?buildId=%teamcity.build.id%"/>
    </properties>

</build>'
```

you can skip `lastChanges` for run the build on the Latest changes