# ASP.NET MVC4 - How can I emulate an HTTP POST request (HttpRequestMessage) so I can debug locally w/o having to rely on a third party device?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, asp.net-web-api

Here's the scenario: We have an iOS app that makes an HTTP POST request to my .NET Web API.  The method that is invoked is `PostPicture` (below):

```
// POST api/blah
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostPicture(HttpRequestMessage msg)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        etc...
```

As you can see, this method takes in an `HttpRequestMessage`.  The issue I'm having is I constantly have to rely on the iOS app to make the call just to be able to pass in the `HttpRequestMessage` to test my .NET code.

I had the iOS developer send me the HTTP POST contents that the device (iOS) is sending to my Web API.  He sent it in a text document.

**Question:** Is there any way to take those raw contents and basically emulate an HTTP POST request with these contents (and of course create an `HttpRequestObject` based on those contents) within my code?

Here's the HTTP POST contents that he sent me:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf370
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Bold;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red81\green112\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab529
\pard\tx529\pardeftab529\pardirnatural

\f0\b\fs22 \cf0 \CocoaLigature0 2013-06-14 15:17:32.969 blah[11765:907] insertEntity URL: http://domain/blahWS/API/blah/PostPicture\
\pard\tx529\pardeftab529\pardirnatural

\f1\b0 \cf0 Printing description of mikeTest:\
\{\
  "imageDataBlob" : "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp\\/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAg\\nUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbG...",\
  "layer" : "0",\
  "blah" : "YES",\
  "pdf" : "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp\\/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAg\\nUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbG...",\
  "imageCount" : "3",\
  "groupID" : "1_userName",\
  "longitude" : -95.98030149945615,\
  "latitude" : 36.74866412304039,\
  "JsonData" : "[\{ \\"geometry\\" : \{\\"x\\":-95.98030149945615 , \\"y\\": 36.74866412304039\} ,\\"attributes\\":\{ \\"Feature\\" : \\"Chemical_Treatment\\",\\"Type\\" : \\"\\",\\"Prod_Name\\" : \\"\\",\\"Line_Dia\\" : \\"\\",\\"Line_Mat\\" : \\"Select\\",\\"Prspct_Fld\\" : \\"\\",\\"Comments\\" : \\"\\",\\"HTML_LINK\\":\\"http:\\/\\/subdomain.url.net\\/blahWS\\/ImageViewer\\/Display\\/1_userName_2013-06-14_15:17:02\\",\\"APP_LAT\\":\\"36.74866412304039\\",\\"APP_LONG\\":\\"-95.98030149945615\\", \\"groupID\\":\\"1_userNamep_2013-06-14_15:17:02\\"\}\}]",\
  "Timestamp" : "2013-01-01 12:12:23",\
  "username" : "_userName"\
\}\
\pard\tx529\pardeftab529\pardirnatural

\f0\b \cf2 (lldb) }
```

Comment: I'd tackle it by using the CURL utility.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Fiddler`](http://fiddler2.com/) to simulate a request easily using The Composer.

NOTE: The request this developer sent you looks like some RTF file rather than an actual [`HTTP`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) request. You might familiarize himself that an HTTP request contains 2 parts: HTTP headers and body payload that you will need in order to perform an HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.  I appreciate it.  I am completely unfamiliar with this territory.  I will mess with Fiddler and I informed the developer of what you said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HttpClient` class in .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: Thanks, I will try Fiddler out first.  HttpClient sounds promising as well.  Appreciate it.