# Feeding a local file as parameter for data input for a CURL request

Tags: curl, command-line, terminal

I'm new and super excited about doing stuff directly from the console! : )

Today I was playing around with the [meaningcloud API](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/lemmatization-pos-parsing/doc) for Lemmatization etc. and it is working great when I input text directly into the URL as a parameter like `txt=here%20my%20text`.

However, when trying to feed input from a file, using the `doc=` parameter as described [in their docs](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/lemmatization-pos-parsing/doc/2.0/request), I keep getting the following response:

```
{"status":{"code":"200","msg":"Missing required parameter(s) - [txt]", ...
```

The docs read that I can use either `doc`, `url` or `txt` as parameter to specify the source of the text input, but it seems I am doing something wrong here.

I tried around for a while with different versions of absolute and relative paths, but couldn't figure out how to get it to take input directly from a file.

Here's one example call that I was making, maybe someone can point me to my error (In the real calls I have my API key in there instead of `{my_key_here}`!):

```
curl -K -XPOST "https://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0?key={my_key_here}&of=json&lang=es&doc=Users/Martin/Documents/text.txt" >> output.json
```

I tried the more general answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line) but just got the same error response. I'm wondering whether this is a general error of mine, or whether it's specific to the API.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The `-K` option is totally wrong there though, as it will then treat `-XPOST` as a file name to read from... You probably meant lowercase `-k`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. Yes, I copied this without checking up on it!   Read up on it now here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html and there's no need for this at all.

Comment: It's still not working, though, so there must be some other issue in there.

Comment: Well, sure, you can't just make things up to your own wishes. You already wrote an answer to yourself showing a POST that works so probably a plain GET is not working against that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with @Lucas Liu 's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408904/send-post-request-with-data-specified-in-file-via-curl)!

```
curl  -i  -F doc=@text.txt "https://etc."
```

And @Daniel Stenberg's nudging helped me to also figure out my initial error (from the [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)):

> @filename
>
> This will make curl load data from the given file (including any
>   newlines), URL-encode that data and pass it on in the POST.

I was passing my file URL as a string - through not prepending the `@` symbol. So the working version of the original call (in the API's [suggested format](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/lemmatization-pos-parsing/doc/2.0/examples)) looks like that:

```
curl -XPOST "https://api.meaningcloud.com/parser-2.0?key={my_api_key}&of=json&lang=es&doc=@Users/Martin/Documents/text.txt" -o output.json
```

Comment: ...and the "-X POST" is better removed

Comment: Great! It works without "-X POST", thanks again! I assume that's because now I'm passing a file so there's no need to use POST to allow for longer strings, is this correct?

Comment: No, it is because -F implies doing a POST and you insisting on it will only lead to mistakes when you later think of adding `-L` or similar.