# How can I perform an HTTPS POST request that contains a file into the request body using CURL?

Tags: http, curl, https, request

I have the following problem.

I have to perform a **CURL** HTTPS POST REQUEST that put a **myFile.xml** into the request body toward a specific URL (that shoul represent a web service endpoint), something like: https://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW/myproject/xml/manager

How can I do it using **CURL**?

I need to do it to simulate a web service call to analyze the obtained request.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line

Comment: @Paul I think that it could be different because in my case I have specified that I have to use https and not http as protocol

Comment: try using -k to allow insecure connections, or pass the SSL certificate as an argument depending on use case. More in the MAN page https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html