# Why is spring @PostMapping @Requestbody coming in as escaped characters?

Tags: spring, curl, post

I have this spring boot controller method:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/myPath")
public String methodName(@RequestBody String incoming) { ...
```

However if I try to post an XML file to it with curl, like:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/myPath --data-binary @./my/path/my_file.xml
```

the incoming String is all escaped characters, like:

`%3C%3Fxml+version=%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%...`

and it blows up attempting to parse it with `...Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

when it should be like `<?xml version="1.0"` what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not what was happening, but adding `curl --header "Content-Type:text/xml"` fixed it.  I guess the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the above overrides it, which is [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26624046/32453), not sure why, maybe the web framework is assuming some extra encoding is necessary or what not.  You can see which one it is using by running `curl -v` and make sure it's not urlencoded, apparently.