# Is it possible to send a file along side a JSONObject in a Curl POST?

Tags: android, curl, mobile

I should start by saying I'm a novice in Curl/ backend/ server stuff.
I have a local server running in an android app. While the device is connected to my machine via a cable I can POST to that server using Curl. I need to send a .vcf file alongside some arguments in a Curl POST. Is this possible? 
For now, I only send files. This is the POST that I have:

```
curl  -X POST  -i  -F parametername=@/Users/mymachine/Desktop/file.vcf localhost:5000
```

and this is how I retrieve it on the server that runs in my android app:

```
             val inputStream = exchange.requestBody

            try {
                val inputAsString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
                Timber.d("Received a POST $inputAsString")

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e("Error while attempting to parse server response ${e.message}")
            }
```

I created the local server following this example:
https://medium.com/hacktive-devs/creating-a-local-http-server-on-android-49831fbad9ca

Is it possible to wrap the file that I'm sending in a JSONObject and add more fields?
Something like this is what I'm after:

```
curl  -X POST  -i  -F {"vcf_file":"parametername=@/Users/mymachine/Desktop/file.vcf", "name":"Jhon", "surname":"Doe"} localhost:5000
```

If its not possible to wrap everything in a JSONObject...what would be to best approach?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done more investigation and found the answer here

[send/post xml file using curl command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line)

My Curl post looks like this now:

```
curl -X POST --form details='{"bar_test":"bar", "foo": "bar"}' --form  parametername=@/Users/myusername/Desktop/test.vcf  localhost:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think provided you hosted your api / files you can easily get their URLs and place them in the json. But if you want to do an upload for example, you should do a multipart request. Retrofit will definitely be a big help for you, here are some links:

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: Also do note, you will need permissions to read and write access storage if it will be coming from your android device.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the issue very well. The problem I'm facing in not in the android app but in the backend